# Search tags by id with goQuery

Tags: html, go, goquery

I would like to retrieve all the tags with a specific id using Go. Apparently the easiest way to do that is go is to use goquery.

Assume I am looking for `ul` tags with id `MyTag` in a website `site`. I would like to list all the `li` contained in such a `ul`. I never used jQuery before so I feel a little lost.

```
resp, _ := http.Get(site)
httpBody := resp.Body
node, _ := html.Parse(httpBody)
document := goquery.NewDocumentFromNode(node)
document.Find("ul.MyTag").Each(func(i int, ul *goquery.Selection) { //MyTag will not work here
    ul.Find("li").Each(func (i int, li *goquery.Selection){
        ...
   })
})
```

More specitically, my html looks like

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ui id="yes">
            <li key="1">a</li>
            <li key="2">b</li>
            <li key="3">c</li>
            <li key="4">d</li>
        </ui>

        <ui id="no">
            <li key="1">11</li>
            <li key="2">22</li>
            <li key="3">33</li>
            <li key="4">44</li>
        </ui>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I would like to retreive the keys `1,2,3,4`

Bonus question: why Each has an `int` argument? It doesn't seem to be used at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GoQuery uses the same selector syntax as jQuery/CSS. To that end, if you want to find an element with a specific ID .. then you need to use a hash `#` symbol.

```
document.Find("ul#MyTag")...
```

That being said, ID's are *supposed to be unique*. The above code you're using (that I provided in a previous question of yours) .. searches by `class` (the dot `.` notation).

Show us the markup you're using this on and I will be able to see exactly where you're going wrong.

RE: Your bonus question. The `int` argument is the index of the element within its parent. You don't *have* to use it.. it is provided by goquery though.

Comment: Yes I was exactly using that code. I have added a small HTML sample to the question

Comment: Your solution and question are in no way related.. making my answer pointless. You were asking about element IDs.. but your solution has something to do with custom attributes..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I was stuck at the ID part, and combining this with the previous answer I got what I wanted